# Shell Script - syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: shell, shell-script, oracle-database

With the following shell script, why I am getting errors

```
syntax error near unexpected token `else'
```

Shell Script

```
echo "please enter username"
read user_name
echo "please enter password"
read -s pass
echo ${ORACLE_SID}
SID=${ORACLE_SID}
if ["${ORACLE_SID}" != 'Test'] then
sqlplus -s -l $USER_NAME/$PASS@$SID <<EOF
copy from scott/tiger@orcl insert EMP using select * from EMP
exit
EOF
else
echo "Cannot copy"
fi
```

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6013802/

Comment: you may want to edit the line "copy from ...." as it may be currently showing something you don't want to show. (However, I do hope those are already modified infos, as they would be really poor security wise)

Comment: @OlivierDulac If you are referring to username and password in that line then those are known to all Oracle database users. It is common and well known since the beginning of Oracle database.

Comment: @OlivierDulac You are welcome, some info about this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_scott_tiger.htm

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to terminate the condition part (the square brackets) like this:

with a semicolon

```
if [ "${ORACLE_SID}" != 'Test' ]; then
                                ^ semicolon
```

or with a newline

```
if [ "${ORACLE_SID}" != 'Test' ]
                                ^ newline
then
```

Note: you also have to put spaces after `[` and before `]`.

```
[ "${ORACLE_SID}" != 'Test' ]
 ^ space                   ^ space
```

---

background

The reason for the `;` or linebreak is that the condition part of the `if` statement is just a command. Any command of any length to be precise. The shell executes that command, examines the exit status of the command, and then decides whether to execute the `then` part or the `else` part.

Because the command can be of any length there needs to be a marker to mark the end of the condition part. That is the `;` or the newline, followed by `then`.

The reason for the spaces after `[` is because `[` is a command. Usually a builtin of the shell. The shell executes the command `[` with the rest as parameters, including the `]` as mandatory last parameter. If you do not put a space after `[` the shell will try to execute `[whatever` as command and fail.

The reason for space before the `]` is similar. Because otherwise it will not be recognized as a parameter of its own.

Comment: That was spot on, however now I am getting `test.sh: line 6: [: missing `]'`

Comment: @lesmana. A good way to provide a wrong answer first, then keep editing before someone else provides the correct answer. Please try to provide the correct answer the first time.

Comment: I do not consider my first answer as wrong. In fact, it was "spot on". It just did not solve *all* the problems in the question.

Comment: `if` *is* syntax, it isn't an ordinary command. It's a reserved word. Unlike many other programming languages, the shell doesn't recognize reserved words everywhere, only when they're the first word of a command (with a few subtleties).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am aware that `if` is syntax. I was trying to communicate that the condition part of the `if` is not constrained to a certain form by syntax. I have edited the text. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 5):

You may easily check your shell scripts using [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) online (also available as a standalone tool).

In this case, it will point out that the if-statement needs spaces, after `[` and before `]`, and that you need a `;` (or a newline) before the `then` on the same line.

When you've fixed that, it will go on to tell you that `USER_NAME` is used without being initialized to anything. This is because you also have a `user_name` variable (case matters). The same is true for `PASS` and `pass`.

It also tells you to use `read -r` to stop `read` from mangling `\` (could be important for passwords, for example), and that you should double quote the variables when calling `sqlplus` to prevent the shell from accidentally doing file name globbing and word splitting (again this is important if the password, for example, contains file globbing characters like `*`, or spaces).

Indenting the code will make it more readable too:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p 'please enter username: ' user_name
IFS= read -rs -p 'please enter password: ' pass

printf 'ORACLE_SID = %s\n' "$ORACLE_SID"
sid=$ORACLE_SID

if [ "$sid" = 'Test' ]; then
    echo 'Cannot copy' >&2
    exit 1
fi

sqlplus -s -l "$user_name/$pass@$sid" <<'SQL_END'
copy from scott/tiger@orcl insert EMP using select * from EMP
exit
SQL_END
```

Here I've also made it possible to use passwords with leading or trailing space characters by temporarily setting `IFS` to an empty string for the password reading `read`.

The logic was also changed to bail out if `$ORACLE_SID`/`$sid` is `Test`. This avoids having the main operational part of the script in an `if` branch.

Comment: Note that `if ([ x = x ]) then (echo yes) fi` also works.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, yes. And that may be interesting form the point of view of a program generating shell code, but it's not how one usually writes `if` statements with `[ ... ]`... :-)

Answer (score 2):

When writing `sh` you'd want

```
if [ "$ORACLE_SID" != "Test" ]
then
  ...
fi
```

When writing `bash`

```
if [[ "$ORACLE_SID" != "Test" ]]
then
  ...
fi
```

Mind the spaces please. There must be a space between `[[` and first operator.